# How to programmatically add bindings to the current class scope in Python?

Tags: python

Though the question is very specific, I'd also really appreciate general advice and other approaches that would make my question moot. I'm building **a collection** of AI programs, and many of the functions and classes need to deal with a lot of different states and actions that cause transitions between states, so I need a way to represent states and actions. Please note that I'm not building a simple state machine, but rather a number of different programs (agents) that all take states and return actions as a way of interacting with an environment.

I could use strings, but that's messy if a particular algorithm needs to associate additional information with a state or action, and comparing strings over and over again in long-running programs is wasted overhead. The same sorts of problems arise with other kinds of constants. So my initial idea is to use nested classes, like so:

```
class DerivedAgent(Agent):
    class StateA(State): pass
    class StateB(State): pass
    ...
    def do_something(state):
        if state is self.StateA:
           ...
```

This works fairly well, but if there are a number of states and actions, it can take up a lot of space to declare them all, and all of the pass statements are annoying. I'd like to be able to do something like...

```
class DerivedAgent(Agent):
    states("StateA", "StateB", "StateC", ...)
```

But I don't see a way to have the `states` method add the newly-created types to the `DerivedAgent` class. I think I might be able to do it with the `inspect` module, but that feels like it's going too far for a small convenience. Is using types like this a bad idea? Is there a much more elegant approach? Code outside of the agent classes will need to be able to access the states and actions, and putting states into the module namespace isn't a good option because a given module might have several agents in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use meta classes so that you would end up with code like:

```
class DerivedAgent(Agent):
    __states__ = ['StateA', 'StateB', ...]
```

for example:

```
class AgentMeta(type):
    def __new__(meta, classname, bases, classdict):
        for clsname in classdict['__states__']:
            classdict[clsname] = type(clsname, (State,), {})
        return type.__new__(meta, classname, bases, classdict))
```

then, just rewrite your `Agent` class so that it has the line

```
#python3.x
class Agent(Base1, Base2, ..., BaseN, metaclass=AgentMeta):
    #everything else unchanged

# 2.2 <= python <= 2.7 
class Agent(Base1, Base2, ..., BaseN):
    __metaclass__ = AgentMeta
    #everything else unchanged
```

If you don't want to change the `Agent` class, you can just include the approriate declaration of metaclass in each subclass of it that you create.

Comment: That's exactly the sort of trick that I was hoping might exist. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: glad i could help. You might want to add a check to make sure that `__states__` exists in classdict before you try to read it ;) I forgot that part. or you could just do `for clsname in classdict.get('__states__', []):`

Answer (score 1):

Explicit state machines are boring, you can have implicit state machines in coroutines. But that is probably too much right now.

Anyways `class StateA(State): pass` is exactly the same as `StateA = type("StateA", (State,), {})`. Saves you typing the `pass` ;-)

Comment: +1 for the assist: I'd forgotten that the states were supposed to inherit from `State`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a state machine, build one. A state machine is data-driven which means that the states and transitions are encoded as data, not class hierarchy.

In Python, dictionaries are the mechanism for *ad hoc* polymorphic dispatch:

```
def do_foo(**kwargs):
    pass

def do_bar(**kwargs):
    pass

dispatch = {
    # state : { (transition, next_state) ... }
    0: {'a' : (do_foo, 1)},
    1: {'a' : (do_bar, 0)},
    1: {'b' : (do_bar, None)}, # None -> accept
}

def state_machine(state, input):
    """does the action corresponding to state on input and returns new state"""
    current = dispatch[state]
    if input in current:
        functor, next = current[input]
        functor(lexeme=input)
        return next

state = 0
for c in 'aaab':
    state = state_machine(state, c)
    if state is None:
        print 'accepted'
        break
```

Comment: I don't want a state machine, but you do provide a nice example of how one might be implemented in Python. I didn't say anything about class hierarchies; rather I'm thinking of using classes as data to encode state, just like you use integers to do the same thing in your implementation of a state machine.